# Regex for log lines that may be slightly different from each other- in spark

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I could write a regex for matching one log line. But my file contains some log lines which differ from the other log lines in that there are just a few extra fields or in a few, the key value pairs are mixed up.

Eg. one log line :
 `case_id=1 event_id=35654423 date=30-12-2010 time=11.02 activity=registerrequest name=Pete costs=50 rerr="-"`

another one : `case_id=1 event_id=35654424 date=31-12-2010 time=11.07 costs=400 rerr="-" activity=examinethoroughly name=Sue rloc="-"`

My log pattern = `"^([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)"`
This is my code for grouping in spark:

```
match = re.search(LOG_PATTERN,line)
Case_ID = match.group(1)
Event_ID = match.group(2)
Date = match.group(3)
Time = match.group(4)
Activity = match.group(5)
Resource = match.group(6)
Costs = match.group(7)
Rerr = match.group(8)
```

This code would match only the 1st log line.
How do i write a regex so that i can group them in spark without ignoring any of the log lines?

Comment: One remark: Some values are inside quotes and you use `[^\s]+` - that will include quotes in the matches - is it OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a simple regex to grab keys and values:

```
rx = "(\\S+)=(\\S+)"
```

or

```
rx = "(\\w+)=(\\S+)"
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jA0zB2/1).

Then, create a dictionary with `re.findall`:

```
d = dict([(x,y) for x,y in re.findall(rx,line)])
```

Then, you have access to each key-value.

Comment: I tried the above code but i get an error for the collect command saying that the input path is wrong even though i've given the correct one. I've added my code to the question.

Comment: So, the error does not pertain to the regex at all, it only says it cannot find the file.

Comment: You're right. Thanks anyway. Will open another question.